# How to attach .then on on google maps places library services

Tags: javascript, reactjs

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places

```
var map;
var service;
var infowindow;

function initialize() {
  var pyrmont = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8665433,151.1956316);

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: pyrmont,
      zoom: 15
    });

  var request = {
    location: pyrmont,
    radius: '500',
    type: ['restaurant']
  };

  service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  service.nearbySearch(request, callback);
}

function callback(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      createMarker(results[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

This is the approach google has mentioned in their docs
But I need to return the result sent by service.nearbySearch to callback(results, status)

Insteed of using callback I wanna do it using .then or await

something like

Get result of service.nearbySearch into variable (e.g. result__ )
let result__ = await service.nearbySearch(request);

or

service.nearbySearch(request)
.then(()=>{})

Comment: Doesn't look like Promises are available for the Places API - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/promises

Comment: does it means that there is no way to get the results and return in same function